# Internet explorer 8 memory consumption

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

On an asp.net website, and only on a few workstations I have the following problem on IE8 :

By using the website, the memory consumption of IE grows and is going above 100 megabytes, from the moment it goes above 90 megabytes, browsing the website becomes extremelly slow or is impossible.

Unfortunately this behaviour is only reproduced on some PCs. The others are correctly releasing memory and IE never goes above 50 megabytes.

All tested systems were Windows XP SP3 with IE 8 8.0.6001.18702 but with different harwares (From Core 2 duo/2Gb to Core i5/4Gb). I even was able to reproduce it in a (Win7/IE9 9.0.8112.16421) virtual machine provided by Microsoft (App compat).

I think the problem is on the client side but to make sure the problem is not coming from my website I decided to make a simple website (based on the VS2010 ASP.net Web application template) to reproduce the problem  :

Default.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('clickHome();',500);">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonHome" runat="server" onclick="LinkButtonHome_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function clickHome() {
                    document.getElementById("<%=LinkButtonHome.ClientID %>").click();
                }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LinkButtonHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>  

    <appSettings />
    <connectionStrings />
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">

          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies>

        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->

      <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpModules>

    </system.web>

    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
     </compilers>
    </system.codedom>

    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
        <remove name="ScriptResource" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

</configuration>
```

I thought I would have to add components from my website but I managed to reproduce the problem on the same computers with this simple website.

I'm sure I'm missing something but IE is the only browser that can be used in my case and I don't know where else to look,

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: I do not understand the logic behing the code here, is a loop to the same page, you have done this to test the memory, or this is the actually problem page ?

Comment: This is a test project that I created to reproduce the problem outside my website, it is looping on the same page because this is how the problem was reproduced on the website. It was reproduced by clicking a 'home' link several times. The debug is true because the web.config was created by VS2010 and I forgot to turn the debug off

Answer (score 1):

As you describe the error is a memory leak that happends on every page load. The possibility to be a leak from javascript use is small because you have this even with a minimum page, so the next that I am thinking is the IE addons.

**So I think that one of your add on have memory leak.**

I suggest to find and disable all non used IE Extensions.

Open the IE and from the Menu Tools, open the Manage Add-ons and click one by one and disable all the non needed ones. Maybe even all just to see if this is the issue.

Alternative you can download the [autoruns from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and look also for IE addons that you can disabled them also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I will try this soon and come back with the results.

Comment: Today I only have access to the Win7/IE9 virtual machine, I disabled all the addons but unfortunately I still have the same behaviour.

Comment: By the way, it is possible to launch IE without addons by using the -extoff argument

Comment: @Bren The next think is to give me the url to see what is loading and make tests.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, the website on which the problem has been found is an intranet website. Today I continued my research and I know the problem is definitely on the client side because I tried a fresh Win7/IE9 VM from microsoft and I don't have the problem. So, I'll be focusing on this VM and compare it with the one which has the problem. Once I found the source of the problem, I'll update this post. I don't think you can help me more than you already did, but thanks a lot for your interest

Comment: @Bren good luck. Try also the autoruns !!! do it ! and maybe you find the one that make the problems